# How to create a container that supports addition of objects and numpy slicing?

Tags: python, numpy

I will describe the simplest use case in which I fail to use numpy in a way that seems quite intuitive to me, and would require some extra level of abstraction:

```
import numpy as np
```

1. Assume an object `MyObj` which has some fields, namely `x, y, z`. Thee fields are numpy ndarrays:

example:

```
x_shape = (1,2,3)
y_shape = (5,6,7,8,9)

def MyObj(object):
    def init(self):
        self.x = np.zeros(x_shape)
        self.y = np.zeros(y_shape)
```

2. I would like to manage these objects in a container that allows me to add objects one by one, efficiently,

example:

```
my_obj1 = MyObj()
my_obj2 = MyObj()
my_obj3 = MyObj()
my_obj4 = MyObj()
objs = MyContainer()  # this is what the question is about
objs.append(my_obj1)
objs.append(my_obj2)
objs.append(my_obj3)
objs.append(my_obj4)
```

3. The container should support **efficient** access to its fields, as if it were a numpy ndarray whose shape is the same as the desired field, with an extra first dimension, with the same size as the objects in the container:

example:

```
assert objs.x.shape == (len(objs),) + x_shape  # (4,1,2,3)
assert objs.y.shape == (len(objs),) + y_shape  # (4,5,6,7,8,9)
access_to_field = objs.x[:, 0,0,0] # access to the first element in X of all objects in the container. **This has to be efficient, just like a numpy view**
```

---

I could not find a native way to do this in numpy, and I want to know the best practice for this standard use case.

Comment: This seems less about OOP but more about [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), which NumPy doesn't support.

Comment: Your best option is to try *not* to do this. It's not an efficient way to work with the underlying data structures.

Comment: If you really want to do this, your best approach is probably to completely implement this on your own (e.g the MyCollection class, the MyCollectionView class etc..)

Comment: @NilsWerner: It's not really jagged, though it might look that way at first glance. The `x` and `y` arrays have incompatible shapes, but the question doesn't ever try to access `x` and `y` data as part of the same array or array-like interface. It tries to access multiple objects' `x` arrays as if they were one larger array. It's still not efficient (there'll be an uncomfortable amount of data copying and/or indirection), but it's not as problematic as trying to stuff `x` and `y` data into the same array.

Comment: A NumPy array needs to have constant strides, so what you are asking [is not possible in the NumPy memory model](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/How-to-concatenate-two-arrays-without-duplicating-memory-td24121.html).

Comment: @user2357112 allright, then what is the correct way of approaching this? I wouldn't want to carry a bunch of arrays around the entire code, this lacks encapsulation, is not modular, and very easily explodes. This seems like a common use case, isn't it?

Comment: @Gulzar: One common technique is to separate the data accumulation and data processing phases. Instead of trying to support mixed "add data" and "access data" operations, gather up all your data up front, make one big `x` array and one big `y` array, and then process that data without trying to add more. I don't know whether your program can be adapted to work that way. You may have to do something else, or combine it with other techniques. As with any data structure, using NumPy arrays comes with tradeoffs.